# Problem printing ${el }, I want to print the content of the element but it prints $%7Bel%7D

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

Problem printing ${el }, I want to print the content of the element but it prints $%7Bel%7D.
It seems that the jinja detects the component ${el} as its variable.

```
const heroesJson = [{
    "images": [
    "Abaddon_icon.png",
    "Alchemist_icon.png",
    "Ancient_Apparition_icon.png",
]
}]
const divHeroes = document.querySelector('#heroes')
let html = ''
let arrayHeroe = heroesJson[0].images
arrayHeroe.forEach((el)=>{
    html+=`<div><img class='w-20' src="{{url_for('static', filename='img-dota/${el}')}}"></div>`
})
console.log(html)
```

The console.log prints : ***"/static/img-dota/$%7Bel%7D.png"...."***

Comment: I have tried your code it was working perfectly.

<div><img class='w-20' src="{{url_for('static', filename='img-dota/Abaddon_icon.png.png')}}"></div><div><img class='w-20' src="{{url_for('static', filename='img-dota/Alchemist_icon.png.png')}}"></div><div><img class='w-20' src="{{url_for('static', filename='img-dota/Ancient_Apparition_icon.png.png')}}"></div>

i tried it in chrome. can you please how you run (enviroment) your code?

Comment: In my case its working.only i added let keyword at the time of arrayHeroe declaration.because it showing error on for loop line.for me it is printing as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing server-side rendered templates with client side rendered templates. They cannot work together like this, because they have different runtime environment. We need to store the URL prefix in a JS variable and use only JS variables during the `forEach` loop that runs on the client side:

```
const heroesJson = [{
    "images": [
    "Abaddon_icon.png",
    "Alchemist_icon.png",
    "Ancient_Apparition_icon.png",
]
}]
const divHeroes = document.querySelector('#heroes')
const url_prefix = "{{ url_for('static', filename='img-dota') }}";  
let html = ''
let arrayHeroe = heroesJson[0].images
arrayHeroe.forEach((el)=>{
    html+=`<div><img class="w-20" src="${url_prefix}/${el}"></div>`
})
console.log(html)
```